# Best way to monitor for a process to start

Tags: c#

I have an app (A) that communicates with another app (B) that I have not written, their is an API I subscribe to.  When B goes down A is notified nicely of this loss of application and all information against it is lost (since the process no longer exists).

I've written a simple threading.timer to essentially poll for when this application comes back to life to then re-initialize itself (A reinitializes to B).

This all works fine and dandy, I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: As they communicate these applications? TCP/IP, COM, Windows Messages.

Answer (score 1):

One thing we have done is to use UDP messaging from the service that you want to monitor.  I am not sure if you have the ability to extend the service B or not however, but if you do then service B can send out the UDP status packets and A can register to receive those UDP packets.  You can determine if a service is down if you do not receive the UDP packets after a certain period of time.  This is more of a push model where what you are describing is more of a polling model.